# CouchDB - Basic design for joins data

Tags: couchdb

Just playing around with CouchDb and CouchApp, what amazing tech ! Very surprised, seams to be very powerful. After playing and reading a lot, as I'm a old relational database user, I still questioning myself about how to design some basic things.

Here is my question :

1/ I have a document of type 'user' and document of type 'item'

2/ My Couchdb contains the following documents :

```
{ "_id": "...", "type": "user", "email":"u1@gmail.com" ... }
{ "_id": "...", "type": "user", "email":"u2@gmail.com" ... }
{ "_id": "...", "type": "user", "email":"u3@gmail.com" ... }
{ "_id": "...", "type": "user", "email":"u4@gmail.com" ... }

{ "_id": "...", "type": "item", "title":"My title",
  created_by:"u1@gmail.com", modified_by:"u3@gmail.com" }
```

3/ Now I want a view or something to fetch document by type=item and _id with informations for each users (creator & modifier)

I have seen a way to emulate a simple join here : http://www.cmlenz.net/archives/2007/10/couchdb-joins

But I can't adapt it for two joins, I'am playing around with key format since few hours, testing lots things, but nothing works.

I think, I'm missing something important with CouchDb map/reduce, if someone has some help I will appreciate it.

PS : Don't answer me to insert 'user' document inside 'item' document. This not my question.

Relax, relax ... :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should put `_id`s in `created_by` and `modified_by`:

```
{ "_id": "u1", "type": "user", "email":"u1@gmail.com" ... }
{ "_id": "u2", "type": "user", "email":"u2@gmail.com" ... }
{ "_id": "u3", "type": "user", "email":"u3@gmail.com" ... }
{ "_id": "u4", "type": "user", "email":"u4@gmail.com" ... }

{ "_id": "anitem", "type": "item", "title":"My title",
  created_by:"u1", modified_by:"u3" }
```

so you can use the following map function and query it with `?key="anitem"&include_docs=true`:

```
function(doc) {
  if (doc.type === "item") {
    emit(doc._id, 1);
    emit(doc._id, { _id: doc.created_by });
    emit(doc._id, { _id: doc.modified_by });
  }
}
```

You can read [Jan Lehnardt's post about it](http://blog.couchbase.com/what%E2%80%99s-new-apache-couchdb-011-%E2%80%94-part-two-views-joins-redux-raw-collation-speed) for more details.

As a side note, I generally put the type in the `_id` so it is easier to get unique keys, and you do not need a view if you only want to filter by type:

```
{ "_id": "user/username1", "email":"u1@gmail.com" ... }
{ "_id": "user/username2", "email":"u2@gmail.com" ... }
{ "_id": "user/username3", "email":"u3@gmail.com" ... }
{ "_id": "user/username4", "email":"u4@gmail.com" ... }

{ "_id": "item/itemid1", "title":"My title",
  created_by:"user/username1", modified_by:"user/username3" }
```

and the map function is

```
function(doc) {
  if (doc._id.slice(0, 4) === "item/") {
    emit(doc._id, 1);
    emit(doc._id, { _id: doc.created_by });
    emit(doc._id, { _id: doc.modified_by });
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:** Due to bug [COUCHDB-1229](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-1229), use of `/` in `doc._id` may cause problems. Depending on your use-case, it may be better to use another separator, e.g. `:` or `_`.

Comment: Thx a lot for your answer, already playing around your tips. :-)

Comment: Yes fine, have made lots tests with your first solution. The key I was missing is that we can emit() further document in the map function.

Comment: But with your second idea with the type/id trick, I don't understand how you fetch the 'item' document with 'user' doc inside ?

Comment: Sorry for my poor English. The type/id trick is only a suggestion on how to choose `_id`s. With CouchDB [I prefer to use natural keys](http://johnpwood.net/2009/06/30/couchdb-databases-and-documents/) instead of serial numbers. I am used to also add the document type to the `_id` because it helps avoid conflicts.

Comment: Oh, I understood simply a trick for readability of keys ;)
But in the CouchDB reference they said : "don't modify the key format unless you know carefully what you do !" Seems i'm a newbie ... :-)

Comment: It depends. In your example I assume each user has a unique username. [This is a perfect fit for user's `_id`](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/cookbook.html#uniqueness). I have edited my answer to make it more clear. If you use a serial number, it is best to stick to the UUID automatically generated by CouchDB.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean here "two joins"? Is this "tableA join tableB ON ... AND ..."?

> Now I want a view or something to fetch document by type=item and _id with informations for each users

This can be done without two/more joins.
Anyway, my advise is to divide your data in 2 databases: items & users. The example above suits only few simple tasks. But when your data grows big (say 10K users & 100K items) it becomes very hard to process your data and it's kinda sucks that all your documents differ from each other with only one field.

Comment: Sorry, i think you don't understand my question or you don't understand how CouchDB works for indexing document in view. But thanks for try helping. See this link : http://www.cmlenz.net/archives/2007/10/couchdb-joins I want to do the same thing but with 2 foreign keys.